# null written inside a file that has script in it

Tags: javascript, windows, terraform, unzip

I unzipped a .tar file in windows using 7zip and see **"null null null0000 00000 nullasync mycode{"**

This text file that i have has a script in it which i need to run.I deleted the null and made a readable code but while running the thing i face errors which makes me think if something got encoded like that which is relevant data and i am missing thatthinking it as junk.

I tried decoding using notepad++ but to no avail.Please see the attached image for an example,Any idea what i can do to get the whole file without these charecters?
[image]

Comment: `null` is not `NUL`, and the image doesn't have the text in it that you quoted. But it sounds like whatever software write out the file wrote out a bunch of character 0 (NUL) to the beginning. Sounds like an error. (And yes, the problem with text files is that you usually have to know via some separate information what text encoding has been used, text encoding signatures [like Unicode BOMs] are sadly uncommon. The NULs aren't related to text encoding, but the further trouble you had may be.)